# Microsoft Open R (Revolution R) using Two CPUs each with Multple Cores

Tags: r, microsoft-r

Good morning.

I know it's relatively easy to spread the computation of a monte carlo simulation across multiple cores on one CPU using Microsoft Open R (running Windows 10), but can you run the processing across 2 CPUs each with say 12 cores on one machine?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you are using the Microsoft `RevoUtilsMath` package, you will get multi-threading "for free" on a multi-processor, multicore machine. See more [here](https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread). There are also CRAN packages available to support multicore. Couple of examples: [here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/rth.html), and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/index.html).

If you use Microsoft R Server, the RevoScaleR functions are parallel.